# How kotlin pattern-matching work as scala

Tags: scala, kotlin, jvm

Now my project needs to change jvm language from scala to kotlin; but how can I use kotlin pattern -matching as scala.

```
    val a: String = "a"
    val b: Int = 1
    (a, b) match {
      case (str: String, i: Int) => // do something
      case (_,_) => // do other thing
    }
```

For the above scala code, what's the kotlin code?

kotlin pattern-matching impl by `when`, but `when` only accept one argument, can `when` accept more than one argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't actually have *patterns*, in the sense of *recursive* pattern matching like in C#, Swift, or Haskell.

`when` with an argument *seems* like it can pattern match, but in reality a case ina `when` only supports a finite number of things that you can do (see [language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#when-expressions)):

- Checking the argument's type - `is SomeType`, `!is SomeType`. The argument will also be [smart-casted](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) to the type if the check succeeds.
- Checking containment - `in someCollection`, `!in someCollection`. This basically just calls `contains`.
- Checking equality against any other expression.
- `else`

You can't *compose* these things in the same way that you can do in other languages.

Assuming the types of `a` and `b` are unknown, I would just write this code using an `if`:

```kotlin
if (a is String && b is Int) {
    // a and b will be smart-casted inside here
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

if there are multiple cases, you can use a `when` *without* an argument.

```kotlin
// a and b will be smart-casted to the appropriate types in each case
when {
    a is String && b is Int -> ...
    a is Int && b is String -> ...
    // and so on
}
```

Note that making a `Pair` from `a` and `b` and check the type of the pair does not work:

```kotlin
when (a to b) {
    is Pair<String, Int> -> ...
    ...
}
```

This is because generic types are erased at runtime. The runtime does not know whether it is a `Pair<String, Int>` or `Pair<Int, String>` or any other kind of `Pair`. It can only check it is indeed a `Pair`, and not a `String` or `Triple`.

Comment: Thanks. So we can interpret `when` as the simplified form and more powerful `if...else-if...else`, is it?

Comment: @shouriken I don't think `if` is *strictly* more powerful than `when`. If you consider only `when`s without an argument, then it is just as powerful as `if`, just a shorter way to write it, and looks nicer in some situations. `when`s *with* an argument on the other hand, is more powerful than `if` - it additionally has exhaustiveness checking for enum classes.

Comment: Ok, the same opinion with you, `when` is more powerful and has nicer coding than `if`. But scala's pattern-matching seems more effective for me, possibly because i'm more familiar with scala. thx again.